# Добавление столбца в БД, если такого нет

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, запрос

Нужно добавлять столбец с ID пользователя если еще такого не существует при старте бота.

````
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    id_user = message.message_id
    await message.answer(f'Привет {message.from_user.full_name} \n\n' '<i>Выбери кнопку в меню.</i>',
                          parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
    sql_start(f'ALTER TABLE words ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXIST "{id_user}" ')


# __________________________ Создание_базы _____________________

def sql_start(reqwest):
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('words.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('База подключена')
    cur.execute(reqwest)
    base.commit()
    ```

Такой запрос ```ALTER TABLE words ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXIST "{id_user}" ``` выдает ошибку, как сделать правильно?
````

Comment: Вы хотите для каждого юзера по столбцу добавлять? (звучит как так себе план)

Comment: Если пользователей будет всего 3, то не думаю